# Problems with ros instalation

Tags: ros, installation, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a beginner in linux and ros.
I am trying to install ros electric on a ubuntu 10.04 distribution and I am having an odd problem.
Following the instructions on the ros wiki installation page I get everything right until it is time to source the setup.bash. What happens is that the folder /opt/ros/electric only contains a subfolder called stacks and nothing else, so I can't find the setup.bash file.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

I have tried to uninstall it and installing it back again, but I get the same situation.

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48415/problems-with-ros-instalation/) by [João Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3550/jo%C3%A3o-pedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
Please either provide a link to the instructions you followed or add the steps to your question by **editing** it.

**Comment by [João Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3550/jo%C3%A3o-pedro/) on 2012-11-15**:
I installed it following the instructions from the link http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install ros Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04

---

Originally posted by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) with karma: 120 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0